# How can I accept cookies on a particular site?

Tags: java, selenium

When writing a basic search test for a job website in Selenium Java, I ma having problems when trying to accept the cookie warning displayed on the site.

The site has 2 cookie notifications, a middle layer and top layer banner that sit on each other.

I would be grateful for any suggestions (I'm new to Selenium Java!) that would allow me to get past this somewhat irritating (but minor) issue.

This is the code I am using to no avail (both cookie banners remains in place):

I have attempted the xpath approach detailed below

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

importnet.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.DiscoveryStrategy.Explicit;
//These are being imported from the Selenium package supplied via Project Level Build Path>External Libraries

```
public class Demo4SeleniumTypeAndClickXPathExperis {

public static void main(String[] args) {


System.setProperty("webdriverchrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();


driver.get("https://www.experis.co.uk/");//Browser URL

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

//here is the offending item that seems to achieve no result

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Accept Cookies']")).submit();


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"query\"]")).sendKeys("test or tester or qa");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search\"]/span/div/div[1]/input")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search\"]/span/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("Bristol");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search\"]/span/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search\"]/span/div/div[1]/input")).submit();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search\"]/span/div/div[1]/input")).submit();     
    //driver.close();




}

private static Object navigate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
```

I am expecting to be able to accept the cookie banners and clear them from the screen

Comment: Why you submit button instead of click on it?

Comment: Hi,I've since edited to a click, but the result is the same, the cookie message remains on screen?

Comment: Dunno. Works in my code. Noticed that cookie warning appear with some animation do you wait for it?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to accept both the cookies alert.
I've tested the code on the you URL you provided in your code.

```
    By cookies_accept = By.xpath("//*[@title='Accept Cookies']");
    By cookies_gotIt = By.xpath("//a[text()='Got it!']");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(cookies_accept)).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(cookies_accept));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(cookies_gotIt)).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a more specific answer, I recommend posting the HTML page source which includes HTML for the cookie accept button.

In my experience with accepting cookies, you might have to treat the popup as an alert:

`driver.switchTo().alert().accept;`

Comment: My apologies, only just seen this - thanks for your time

Comment: No problem, hope you got your code working!

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.selenium_abcd;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class cookiesDelete {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver dr = new ChromeDriver();
        dr.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        dr.manage().deleteCookieNamed("Cookie name");
        

    }

}
```